# How to convert Python Script In MATLAB for Silhouette Criteria

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, deep-learning

I hope you are doing well.
I have the following python code. I am trying to write in MATLAB But facing the issue in some command.

Here is the code in Python

```
costs = []
for p in range(10):
    kmeans = K_Means(k=p,data = data[0],centeriod_init='random')
    centroids, cluster_assignments, iters, orig_centroids = kmeans.fit(data[0])
    X = data[0]
    dist_ji = 0
    a = 0
    s=0
    for i in range(len(data[0])):
        for j in range(p):
            dist_ji += euclidean_dist(centroids[j,:],X[i,:])
            #print(dist_ji)
    dist_ji -= sum(cluster_assignments[:,1])/len(data[0])
    a = sum(cluster_assignments[:,1])/(len(data[0])-1)
    s = (dist_ji - a)/max(dist_ji,a)
    s = np.array(s)
    s =  s.item()
    costs.append(s)
x = np.arange(10)
```

Here is the following MATLAB code i have implmented yet

```
costs=[]
tic
for p=1:10
    [ClusterIndexes,Centroids,sumd]=kmeans(dataset1,p);
    X=dataset1;
    dist_ji=0;
    a=0;
    s=0;
    for i=1:length(dataset1)
        for j=1:10
        dist_ji=pdist2((Centroids(j,:)), X(i,:));
        end
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: kmeans is definitely the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many great examples of [silhouette criterion clustering](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/silhouette.html) and [plotting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.silhouetteevaluation.html) in the MATLAB documentation for the Stats and Machine Learning Toolbox.

Here's my approach based on what I know from what you have provided. I created some random data so you can try out the code. I just tried this on [MATLAB Online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/) and got results, but I can't compare it to the output of your code in Python. This might help get you started.

```
rng('default')  % For reproducibility
data = [randn(100,2)+ones(100,2);randn(100,2)-ones(100,2);randn(100,2)+[-2 2]];

costs = [];

for p = 1:10
    [cluster_assignments,centroids] = kmeans(data,p,'Distance','sqeuclidean','Start','sample');
    dist_ji = 0;
    for i = 1:length(data)
        for j = 1:p
            dist = pdist2(centroids(j,:),data(i,:),'euclidean');
            dist_ji = dist_ji + dist;
        end
    end
    a = sum(cluster_assignments)/(length(data)-1);
    s = (dist_ji - (sum(cluster_assignments)/length(data)))/max(dist_ji,a);
    costs = [costs,s];
end
x = 1:10;

plot(x, costs);
xlabel('Number of clusters');
ylabel('Cost');
```

Comment: basically the silhouette criterion clustering  takes more time to find optimal cluster, thats why i am implementing it from scratch.

Comment: the algo you shared in MATLAB does not work as In python. Can you please look again whats the problem, which thing is missing.

Comment: Can you share some data and the output of the Python code? I will try to see what's going on with the differences.

Comment: How can i share data here?

Comment: Let's try Trinket: https://trinket.io/python/f388cfcc26